# Searchbar "if" statement keeps showing "else" result

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to make a custom search bar for my app and it works fine but I need to include a if/else statement to let my user know that the user he searched for does not exist.I tried implementing a if/else statement but when I try to search a user that's in my database it shows me my else statement of "Username not found" when I know I'm putting in the right Username.

From the code I provided I would like to know what am I doing wrong?

```
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String Username = sbar.getText().toString();
        String foundplayer = db.getUsername();
         if (Username.equals(foundplayer)) {
             ResultFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             ResultText.setText(foundplayer);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }    
    }

});

public String getUsername() {
    String[] userName = new String[] { "USERNAME" };
    Cursor c = db.query( "NFDB", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex("USERNAME");
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = c.getString(iName);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that `foundplayer` is `""` and that's why the `if` condition is not satisfied. Did you debug it? The debugger is your friend.

Comment: try Username.equalsIgnoreCase(foundplayer.trim()) instead.

Comment: @Cranosaur Are you sure you  are getting the username?

Comment: Please add `System.err.println(Username + " " + foundplayer);` before `if` statement and see the result! It should help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that your getUsername() method returning value..
If it returns value then do like this.

```
  String foundplayer = db.getUsername();
```

this will take sometime to process as it involves getting the data from Database so your compiler will not wait for it to complete because of that compiler will go to if condition before completing getUsername() method. so you will get your foundplayer null

so it will never satisfy the condition.

so call that in a separate thread and let the other statement wait until it completes

```
  String foundplayer = "";
Thread t=new Thread()
{
public void run()
{
  foundplayer = db.getUsername();
}
};
t.start();
t.join();
```

or

`equals` is case sensitive try `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: What makes you think `db.getUsername()` is asynchronous?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @jahroy May be I am.. Because I have faced this strange situation when I started developing android app. Where I have assigned variable a value returned method from Database call. As my DB involves huge data it took time and each and everytime I get he null value. So What I have did is call it in a separate thread and stop the current thread until the operation completes..

Answer (score 0):

Your `getUsername` function actually returns some *random* user name from the database.

You have to give it the user name to be searched for as a parameter:

```
public String getUsername(String searchName) {
    Cursor c = db.query("NFDB",
                        new String[] { "USERNAME" },
                        "USERNAME = ?",
                        new String[] { searchName },
                        null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToNext())
        return c.getString(0);
    else
        return "";
}
```

For that matter, it's quite pointless to return the user name from that function, because the caller already knows what name was searched for. You should better return a boolean.